# Is it possible for two finite fields with the same characteristic to not be isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Examples of this? I know this is possible with infinite fields but I'm not sure about finite fields.

Comment: Take any two finite fields of characteristic $p$ with a different number of elements ...

Comment: Z/2Z (the ring of congruence classes mod2) and the boolean ring? These have the same number of elements however they are different elements I think.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. For example the finite fields $\mathbb{F}_4$ and $\mathbb{F}_2$ both have characteristic 2, but they dont have the same number of elements so can't be isomorphic.

More generally, there exists a unique finite field (up to isomorphism) which has characteristic $p>0$, and $q=p^n$ elements denoted $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Comment: I am not familiar with the notation F_4 or F_2, what do you mean by these?

Comment: @Jenny, see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Some_small_finite_fields

Comment: I guess I don't really understand those fields. Are there any other examples?

Comment: I suggest if you are not familiar with this notation that you explicitly write out a "multiplication table" for a set with four elements with 0 and 1 and you'll find that you can construct a field with four elements directly.

Answer (score 0):

Every finite field $F$ fails to be algebraically closed.  One can write
$$
f(x) = 1+\prod_{a\in F}(x-a)
$$
and it's easy to see that this polynomial has no roots in $F$.  There is therefore a larger field, of which $F$ is a subfield, having roots of this equation.  That larger field has the same characteristic.

Comment: Either you didn't understand the question or else I don't understand how your answer is related to the OP...and by "algebraically complete" I guess you meant "algebraically closed", didn't you?

Comment: @DonAntonio: This answer explains why finite fields are not algebraically closed, hence have a proper finite extension, which is then a larger finite field - in particular not isomorphic. So this definitely answers the question!

Comment: I see Martin, but either by the basic nature or the question or else by the OP's comments to the other answer, it seems almost clear this is way over the OP's level. The OP doesn't even know the field $\;\Bbb F_4\;$ ...and I was also misled to believe the answer doesn't address the OP.

Comment: Yes, I meant "closed".  I've fixed it.